# How to compare two UTCTime values and get the difference in days?

Tags: haskell, time, haskell-stack

I want to take away from UTCTime - UTCTime. I found the following function:

`diffUTCTime :: UTCTime -> UTCTime -> NominalDiffTime`

But I get the difference in `NominalDiffTime`, and I need to get the difference in days

Is there any function for this?

Something other than `nominalDiffTimeToSeconds`?!

Comment: In *full* days, or as some floating point (that takes remaining hours, etc. into account)?

Comment: What type would you prefer over `NominalDiffTime` or `nominalDiffTimeToSeconds`'s `Pico`? (...and why?)

Comment: Are we furthermore talking about *solar days*, or *sidereal days*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just need to get the difference in days. In my code, I take the current date from the date the user entered.
Example: // "Pls Enter Date"
2018-10-06
and from this date I take away the current and get the difference in days
That is, this number is 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
daysDiff :: UTCTime -> UTCTime -> Int
daysDiff t t' = round(diffUTCTime t t' / nominalDay)
```

Explanation:

`NominalDiffTime` is, among others, a `Fractional`, so you can divide your result with `nominalDay`:

```
Prelude Data.Time.Clock> myDiffTime / nominalDay
2.314814814814s
```

You can use its `RealFrac` instance to `round`, `floor`, etc. it:

```
Prelude Data.Time.Clock> round $ myDiffTime / nominalDay
2
Prelude Data.Time.Clock> truncate $ myDiffTime / nominalDay
2
Prelude Data.Time.Clock> floor $ myDiffTime / nominalDay
2
Prelude Data.Time.Clock> ceiling $ myDiffTime / nominalDay
3
```